# How to add a block of code in question?

Tags: support, markdown, code-block

I am new here & trying to ask a question about C++ on Stack Overflow.

The question contains a long code & I don't know how to add it in short time. I tried to use *code sample* tool provided there but it added only a line at a time. So, please help me with this.

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enter code simply by copying and pasting it into the question. You *format* it by selecting it all and clicking the <kbd>{ }</kbd> buttom.

However, try to cut the code down to the minimum amount (less than 100 lines if possible) before posting. See this help page regarding [creating a minimum, compilable, valid example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details